# How can I rotate a mesh grid matrices about all axes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, rotational-matrices

The purpose of this code is to plot a mesh to show a robot with two thrusters. The position of the robot is defined by the vector: position. The orientation of the robot is defined by a forward unit vector (front of the robot), and an upward unit vector (top of the robot). I have created the three ellipsoids to show the robot without any rotation performed. How do I rotate the model to fit the defined orientation unit vectors? How do I translate the model to fit the position coordinates?

Code so far:

```
%inputs to function
forward_vector = [-1 0 0];
upward_vector = [0 0 1];
position = [0 0 0];

%define inital robot shapes
[x1, y1, z1] = ellipsoid(0,0,0,1,0.5,0.5,15);
[x2, y2, z2] = ellipsoid(0.6,0.4,0,0.5,0.25,0.25,15);
[x3, y3, z3] = ellipsoid(0.6,-0.4,0,0.5,0.25,0.25,15);

%rotation?


%plot
surf(x1, y1, z1)
hold on
surf(x2, y2, z2)
surf(x3, y3, z3)
hold off
axis equal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate ellipsoids after drawing them.
Short example:

```
[x1, y1, z1] = ellipsoid(0,0,0,1,0.5,0.5,15);
el1 = surf(x1, y1, z1);
rotate(el1, [0,1,0], 90)
```

`rotate` function can take multiple arguments: angles or vector and angle. 
Type `help rotate` in command windows to get docs and example.
You will need to compute angles between default position and current orientation vector.